# Find a String in a 10k line files in Java efficiently

Tags: java

I need to check if the password that an user entered is contained in a 10k lines .txt file that is locally stored in my computer. I've been asked to do this for a college project and they've been very emphatic about achieving this in an efficent manner, not taking too long to find the match.

The thing is that reading the file line by line using a BufferedReader the match is done almost instantly.

I've tested it in two computers, one with an ssd and the other one with an hdd and I cannot tell the difference.

Am I missing something? Is there another and more efficent way to do it? For example I could load the file or chunks of the file into memory, but is it worth it?

Comment: You need to mention what is the time it is taking right now and what you are expecting. There are so many factors e.g. CPU, OS etc. and therefore unless until you mention all of these things in your question, it is too broad to be answered.

Comment: Best is probably to use a ring buffer to progressively read bytes into, check the bytes against those of the String. Why ring buffer: because the string could be split across two buffer 'blocks', so you need the capability to process byte block seamlessly. Discard checked bytes, load more bytes into ring buffer. For byte comparison the CPU is fast enough so that you multi-threading will not have much of an impact. For more complex operations, multi-threading might prove well-advised

Comment: Ah and what you're missing: the file is probably already buffered, to HDD/SSD access does not play a role there. Windows 10 uses almost 50% of available RAM for buffering, unless it's needed elsewhere. So it's not uncommon to have multiple GB-sized files buffered.

Comment: Oh, and regarding my first comment: using byte buffers only might speed up search speed by 100%, i.e. make it twice as fast. Haven't tested it. But as long as this check is rare, i.e. 10 times a minute or so, you can go with the "search" solution. If you have to check lots of password per second, you might wanna use some indexing function for words, or drop them into a HashMap/Set or something, so you can use targeted search. Also depends on your password policy, if it can contain whitespaces and whatnot, or if you have to consider variations like case or leet replace.

Answer (score 2):

10k passwords isn't all that much and should easily fit in RAM. You can read the file into memory when your application starts and then only access the in-memory structure. The in-memory structure could even be parsed to provide more efficient lookup (i.e. using a `HashMap` or `HashSet`) or sort it in memory for the one-time cost of O(n × log n) to enable binary-searching the list (10k items can be searched with max. 14 steps). Or you could use even fancier data structures such as a bloom filter.

Just keep in mind: when you write "it is almost instant", then it probably already is efficient *enough*. (Again, 10k passwords isn't all that much, probably the file is only ~100kB in size)